# Gradually change fill in SVG element using transform in Snap SVG

Tags: svg, snap.svg, svg-animate

I am trying to simulate gradually "filling" (like water filling a cup) an element in SVG. I run into trouble with mask. For the following, assume inclusion of snap.svg-min.js:

```
<script>
var s = Snap(500,500);
var a = s.rect(0,100,100,100);
var b = s.ellipse(50,50,30,60);
b.attr({
    fill: "white"
});
a.animate({transform: 't0, -100'}, 500, mina.easin);
a.attr({
    mask: b
});
</script>
```

The mask in the a.attr clips the image initially, and shifts that up. I want to fill the ellipse going up.

Somewhat like the inverse of the following:

```
<script>
var s = Snap(500,500);
var a = s.rect(0,100,100,100);
var b = s.ellipse(50,50,30,60);
b.attr({
    fill: "white"
});
a.animate({transform: 't0, -100', mask: b}, 500, mina.easin);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're partly there, there's a few different ways, you could probably also use a clip rather than a mask, but here's the way along the lines I think you were trying...

Swap the mask around..

```
var a = s.rect(0,0,120,120).attr({ fill: 'white', transform: 't0,100' });
var b = s.ellipse(50,50,30,60);

b.attr({
    fill: "red",
    mask: a
});

a.animate({transform: 't0,60' }, 2000, mina.easin)
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5826ywh7/3/)

Comment: Thanks! that works great. I tried something similar, but it wasn't working for me. Perhaps I messed up the syntax.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer if its working.